# Several CSS output with grunt-contrib-compass

Tags: sass, gruntjs, compass-sass, grunt-contrib-compass

I'm using `grunt-contrib-compass` to process my SCSS files into a single CSS file. Basically, compass considers all the SCSS files matching `app/styles/**/*.scss` and compile them into `.tmp/styles/main.css`.

I would like to split this behavior into :

1. `app/styles/specific/**/*.scss`  to  `.tmp/styles/specific.css`
2. `app/styles/**/*.scss`  to  `.tmp/styles/main.css` (ignoring `specific`)

However, I have no idea how to configure grunt regarding my configuration file which is quite simple :

```
options: {
    sassDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles',
    cssDir: '.tmp/styles',
    imagesDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/images',
    javascriptsDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts',
    fontsDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles/fonts',
    importPath: '<%= yeoman.app %>/bower_components',
    relativeAssets: true
}
```

I couldn't figure out any solution especially since the compass documentation states that `cssDir` and `sassDir` only allows string as a parameter. Does this has to be done in an other task?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you should try grunt-contrib-sass that have internal support for compass: 
https://npmjs.org/package/grunt-contrib-sass

from documentation:

```
compass 
Type: Boolean
Default: false

Make Compass imports available and load project configuration 
(config.rb located close to the Gruntfile.js).
```

And you can use global patterns of gruntjs: 
http://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#globbing-patterns

```
sass: {
 dist: {
  files: [
    {
      src: 'app/styles/specific/**/*.scss', 
      dest:'.tmp/styles/specific.css'
    },
    {
      src: ['app/styles/**/*.scss', '!app/styles/specific/**/*.scss'],    
      dest:'.tmp/styles/main.css'
    }
  ]
 }
}
```

Comment: Actually I was using compass because it was embed in the yeoman backbone generator. I'm not using any of its functionality. I will be perfectly fine with `grunt-contrib-sass` and add `compass` in the future if needed.